# Caffe: why Dropout layer exists also in Deploy (testing)?

Tags: neural-network, deep-learning, caffe, conv-neural-network, pycaffe

I understand that Dropout is for efficient training, avoiding over-fitting and speed-up learning. However, I do not understand why i see it also in the deploy (testing)?

Should I set dropout_ratio: 1.0 is testing?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**TL;DR**
 Don't touch dropout layer. Caffe knows it should do nothing during inference.

---

[`"Dropout"`](http://caffe.help/manual/layers/dropout.html) is indeed a very powerful addition to the learning process, and it *seemingly* has no impact at inference time.
However, if you consider a naive implementation where at train time one only set some of the neurons to zero, at test time you must compensate for activating *all* neurons by scaling the activations (to get the same overall "strength" of the signal). In this case inference-time `"Dropout"` becomes a simple scale layer (by known and fixed scale factor).
Fortunately, more thoughtful implementation does this scaling as part of the training (that is, setting some of the neurons to zero, and *simultaneously* scaling up the rest of the neurons be a predefined [scale factor](https://github.com/BVLC/caffe/blob/master/src/caffe/layers/dropout_layer.cpp#L17)), this way, at inference time `"Dropout"` layer does absolutely [nothing][3].

To learn more about `"Dropout"` contribution to the stability of the training and its impact on the generalization capacity of the net you can read sec 7.12 of [Bengio's deep learning book](http://www.deeplearningbook.org/contents/regularization.html).

Comment: so putting dropout layer in deploy or not wont make difference, right?

Comment: @NimaHatami if you trained with recent version of `"Dropout"` layer that does the scaling during training, than you remove dropout completely from your `deploy.prototxt`. looking at the code, caffe does copy input to output which is redundant, so I guess removing the layer completely will be slightly more efficient.